# How to check if is pdf signing is disabled using PDF.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I want to check if the pdf document is readonly more specifically whether the user can modify it by **adding signature.**

When viewing the document's security properties we can see the value "Signing: Not Allowed".

[image: sample pdf properties]

I tried to read the metadata but could not find any flag for this. Any help will be appreciated. Please find the metadata response below.

```
{
  "info": {
    "PDFFormatVersion": "1.7",
    "IsLinearized": false,
    "IsAcroFormPresent": true,
    "IsXFAPresent": false,
    "Title": "Resume",
    "Author": "LinkedIn",
    "Subject": "Resume generated from profile",
    "Creator": "Acrobat Sign",
    "Producer": "Acrobat Sign",
    "CreationDate": "D:20220323065214Z",
    "ModDate": "D:20220407204701-07'00'"
  },
  "metadata": {
    "_metadata": {
      "dc:description": "Resume generated from profile",
      "dc:creator": "LinkedIn",
      "dc:format": "application/pdf",
      "dc:title": "Resume",
      "dc:language": "en",
      "dc:date": "2022-03-23T06:52:14Z",
      "pdf:producer": "Acrobat Sign",
      "pdf:pdfversion": "1.4",
      "pdfuaid:part": "1",
      "xmp:metadatadate": "2022-04-07T20:47:01-07:00",
      "xmp:createdate": "2022-03-23T06:52:14Z",
      "xmp:creatortool": "Acrobat Sign",
      "xmp:modifydate": "2022-04-07T20:47:01-07:00",
      "xmpmm:documentid": "uuid:b6b37f58-7c64-2a45-5f0a-454c97be7809",
      "xmpmm:instanceid": "uuid:ccf84365-bc5a-2d90-5009-454c97be7809"
    }
  },
  "contentDispositionFilename": null
}
```

Comment: Could be that `PDF.js` simply does not support detecting this. Check the docs. If no support is found (which doesn't seem to be the case from your output), check the current PDF file format docs for alternative/official detection.

Comment: At the bottom of the dialog you can read that the author has certified the document to prevent changes. I.e. the author has applied a certification signature with no-changes-allowed. To check this you have to determine the DocMDP transform settings of that signature.